# Interpretation of Monte Carlo results - R

Tags: r, estimation, monte-carlo

I have a question regarding the interpretation of Monte Carlo results.

I am applying the Monte Carlo simulations to an estimate process about development team size. The input distribution of the simulation is a uniform distribution, with of course a defined min and max value.

Given this values, I'm applying the simulation in R by using the mc2d package for the option of uncertainty.

Given these parameters, the simulation produces a set of descriptive statistics. Since I am interested in a single value (an accurate estimation), how can I interpret the results produced by the simulation? How can we for instance get that an estimate of value x is at a certain level of uncertainty.

Thanks in advance!

Updates: results produced by mc2d in R

[image]

Comment: I'm confused by "Since I am interested in a single value (an accurate estimation)". A MC simulation usually gives you a distribution from which you can infer the expected value and variation.

Comment: Maybe I formulated the question badly. The purpose of the simulation is to provides us with probabilities that a value may occur. Given an uniform distribution, how can be make inferences about the probability of value x?

Comment: Can you please show the results? Basically in MC, we average all the possibilities with a confidence interval related to the inverse sqrt-root of the sample size.

Comment: Updated the question with the results produced by R

Answer (score 2):

In a Monte-Carlo, there is no such thing as "a single value (an accurate estimation". You should always report your simulation mean, your confidence interval and sample size. Remember, achieving a MC mean of 3.02 with a sample size of 10 is very different to with a sample size of 1000. In the latter size, you should be more confident that your estimation converges to the true value.

In your example, the MC estimate is 3.02. The results also give you a confidence interval at 2.5% significance level. You should also report the sample size, which I assume 101 (nsu).

Comment: I had initially interpreted the output statistics as quantiles of the Monte-Carlo distribution of something. Because essential details of that simulation have not been disclosed--such as what data it is based on and what the input probability distributions mean--I have been unable to make any reliable connection between those quantiles and a confidence interval for some estimate. Could you explain the basis for concluding that those quantiles are a legitimate confidence interval?

Comment: @whuber The poster did mention it is uniform distribution. Does that answer your question?

Comment: No, it does not, because it does not address what the simulation is doing, what data it is based on, or what probabilistic assumptions it might be making.

Comment: While I certainly don't know about the assumptions (not stated). I've found it hard to believe that the summary statistic from a Monte-Carlo method doesn't produce a confidence interval. The results posted in the question clearly showed it is some kind of quantiles. I don't want to add anything like normality in my answer because I don't want to make the assumption. I think I made the best guess from the data that the poster gave. What do you think that can improve the answer?

Comment: I'm not criticizing the answer.  I just cannot evaluate it at all because the phrase "Monte Carlo simulation" covers so much ground that it's impossible to determine what the output numbers really mean.  For example, it's not uncommon for people to simulate the *population distribution* of a quantity, in which case the output might be interpreted as a tolerance interval rather than a confidence interval. Because there's such a profound difference between the two, that's why I originally asked what it was that told you this is a confidence interval for some estimate.

Comment: You're right but the poster did mention he was simulating the team size. To me, he was trying to simulate a population value. Furthermore, he asked for "a single value", he didn't ask for anything else like a distribution. That was how I came up with my guess.

Comment: A quick check of the [`mc2d` documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mc2d/vignettes/docmcEnglish.pdf) suggests your guess may have missed the mark; instead, the output consists of "quantiles of a risk distribution" rather than quantiles of a *sampling distribution* of an estimate as you have supposed. But I'm still unsure of the details in this particular instance.